# Sscanf and Sprintf convert string to decimal?

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I need to solve the following exercise:

> "Write a program that acquires the first characters of a string an integer octal and write it on another string previously empty, then display the contents of this second string in decimal, using the functions `sscanf` and `sprintf`.
>   For example, if the user enters 12 (octal) the system must show 10 (decimal)."

After my `scanf`, the array `seconda` is `="12325"`.
The problem is that I do not know how to make understand that this string is an octal number and how to convert it to decimal with `sprintf`.

This is my current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char prima[] = "12325dsdfa";
    char secodna[500];

    sscanf_s(prima, "%[0123456789]o", secodna, 500);
}
```

Comment: go from string -> int -> string...

Comment: `unsigned oct_value;  sscanf_s(prima, "%o", &oct_value); sprintf(secodna, "%u", oct_value);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY as it gets if you want to use sprintf_s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mis-using `%o`, mixing it with the character set format `%[]` and also passing too many arguments.

You should just use `%o`, it will convert an unsigned integer octal for as many characters as possible.

Then convert back to decimal string using `%u` with `sprintf()`.

Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned int x;
    if(sscanf("12foo", "%o", &x) == 1)
        printf("%u\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the above outputs the decimal string to stdout rather than keeping it around (i.e. it uses `printf()` instead of `sprintf()`), but that's trivial to change. It prints "`10`".

Comment: with `sscanf_s(prima, "%hho", secodna, 500);` i get this error `'sscanf_s' : too many arguments passed for format string` and `placeholders and their parameters expect 1 variadic arguments, but 2 were provided`

Answer (score 1):

Once it has been converted to a binary integer variable (with sscanf()) use sprintf() with a %u format to output it to the appropriate string.

Make sure you have the appropriate buffers defined first.

[sscanf reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/)

[sprintf reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/)

```
unsigned int intbuf;
char myinput[80];
char myoutput[80];

strcpy(myinput, "12345");
sscanf(myinput, "%o", &intbuf);
sprintf(myoutput, "%u", intbuf);
```

Comment: @chux thanks that is what I get for typing too fast early in the morning.I will fix it